# How do i set up freeglut libraries on Linux Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: c++, opengl, ubuntu-14.04, freeglut

I need to run a GLut project on CodeBlocks 13.12 for my OpenGL game engines, using C++. I only know how to do this on Windows. I have went to the Ubuntu Software Center and installed freeglut3-dev , freeglut-dbg and freeglut3.

What do i do next ?

after i have done what needs to be done, when codeBlocks asks me to specify GLUT's location, where should it be ? is it /usr ?

Answer (score 0):

> codeBlocks asks me to specify GLUT's location

In Linux you normally don't specify the location of system wide installed libraries; at least for development and when packaging for a distribution¹. You just say "link with library of name 'foo'" and the linker system figures out the location by itself. So all you have to do is add the library to the set of linker library flags, i.e. add `-lglut` at the right place.

---

¹: it's a different situation when you create a distribution independent installation archive. However if you have to ask a question like this, it'd hardly help to lecture on how to do *that*.